# Using SQL statement for conditional update tables in access 2013

Tags: sql, ms-access, case

I am new to databases. I am creating an Access database to track the inventory dynamics of our company. I have two tables. One is the current inventory stock, another is consumption raised by production activity. The update is done immediately after each production.

Before doing update, I want to verify the same unit is used in both stock status and consumption sheet. I try to do something like these:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()
   CurrentDb.Execute "SELECT o.Unit, s.Material_Unit" & _
                     "CASE WHEN o.Unite = s.Material_Unit" & _
                     "THEN UPDATE tbl_Current_Stock As o INNER JOIN bl_Temp_Raw_Material_Consumption AS s ON o.Raw_Material = s.[Ingredient/Packaging material] Set o.Stock_Level = o.Stock_Level - s.Consumption" & _
                    " Print'Congratulations! You have successfully updated inventory balance!'" & _
                     "ElSE PRINT ' Units of source data and targeted data are not matched!'" & _
                     "Exit Sub" & _
                     "End" & _
                    "FROM tbl_Current_Stock As o, bl_Temp_Raw_Material_Consumption AS s"
END sub
```

But it seems some errors exist. Please help me on these codes.

Thanks.

Comment: You are conflating SQL and VBA code. And Access  SQL does not support `CASE` statements. Consider reading docs or tutorials on MS Access.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is totally wrong. You can not use `CASE` to datermine which statement to execute, `UPDATE` or `PRINT`(`PRINT` is useless here, in MS Access).

You need to use either:

`IF` statement in your SQL query - declare `o.Unite` and `s.Material_Unit` as variables and compare them, if they match then execute update.

```
IF @unite = @materialunite 
BEGIN
     [Your Update Statement]
END
```

The other way:
Declare VB variables, assign the `o.Unite` and `s.Material_Unit` values to them, and write `IF` - `ELSE` statements in VB and execute your SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks Tedo, I am totally new in sql. I will try your suggestions. have a good day.

Comment: Not to split hairs, but you likely meant VBA, a notable difference from VB. Additionally, your code seems to be SQL Server TSQL and not Access SQL, a different dialect.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, it should be VBA. Also, the user has not specified he is working on local or MS SQL SERVER remote database, so if his back-end is MS SQL, the code will execute and update tables. if he uses local db, he could use VBA conditions and then update statement, as I've written.